# How to delete an element from DOM angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of objects and populated using

```
<div ng-if="model.ready" class="d-group" ng-repeat="group in model.groupedD">
    <d-card ng-repeat="summary in group |
    filter: {dStatusId: model.statusFilter} |
    filter: {isD: model.typeFilter} track by summary.pDId"
```

I want to change one object from the groupD and remove it from the DOM (I am changing some value of the object). I looked into Listening to DOM Changes Using MutationObserver (https://nitayneeman.com/posts/listening-to-dom-changes-using-mutationobserver-in-angular/) and I think it is the way to do this. But seems complex.

When I delete the object it stays same on the web page. The filter has no effect. how to let filter know the value of the object has changed? and remove it from the DOM.

Comment: The `ng-repeat` directive automatically removes an element from the DOM when when an item is removed from the collection that it is watching.

Comment: but it didn't work. after changing the object value I can still see it on the web page.

Comment: when an item is **removed** from the collection. You must **remove** the object from the groupedD array.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your example, you need to make sure that your data-structure is correct, in terms of using `ng-repeat` and `filter`.
Look at the simple example below:
This is HTML template.

```
<label>Search: <input ng-model="vm.searchText"></label>
<div ng-if="vm.model.ready" class="d-group" ng-repeat="group in vm.model.groupedD">
    <span ng-repeat="summary in group.summary | filter:vm.searchText">
        <span>{{summary.a}}{{summary.b}}</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

This is Controller function.

```
let vm = this;
vm.searchText = '';

vm.model = {
    ready: true,
    groupedD: [
        {a: 1, b: 1, summary: [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 2, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 3}]},
        {a: 2, b: 2, summary: [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 2, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 3}]},
        {a: 3, b: 3, summary: [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 2, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 3}]}
              ]
};

return vm;
```

When you input some value to input field, let say `4`, all DOM elements related to `ng-repeat="summary in group.summary | filter.vm.searchText"` is going to be dissapeared.

So my suggestion is to double-check your data-structure and filter condition once again. It difficult to provide the answer without looking on whole data-structure you are using.
P.S I've used `controller as` syntax in my example, simple change to use `$scope` instead, if it's necessary for you.